How do alpha channels work in Blender?
A lot of times I come across models that have alpha channels in the textures (specifically on the diffuse and normal maps). Are these channels necessary for both texture types, and if so, how do I use them?

Both diffuse maps and normal maps shouldn't use alpha. Adding an image example to your question would help.

Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see What should I do if no one answers my question?

Alpha channels define Transparency. If you are using an Image Texture in Blender with an alpha channel, use the shading tab, and connect the alpha component of the Image Texture to the alpha connection on the Principled BSDF. If you are using EEVEE (Pre 4.2), you must also change the material's Blend Mode to something other than opaque.

Alpha channels are most often masks (think stencils) that can be used as a mix factor between a Transparent Shader and one or more other Shaders (although most shader systems often "understand" what's happening if an alpha channnel is being used in conjunction with a diffuse shader and automatically apply it to the Normal Map, thus the Normal map generally does not require an alpha channel).

Black and white textures (including procedural ones) can be used for an alpha channel as well, with white representing opaque and black representing transparent. Shades of grey represent varying levels of semi-transparency depending on the darkness:

